# Prevent left padding from pushing element to the right

Tags: html, css

I have some preview text followed by a link with a rollover, and I'm trying to ensure that the text of the link is aligned with that of the preview text. This works fine without padding:

[image]

However, adding padding to the anchor element causes the whole element to shift to the right by the amount of left padding:

[image]

How can I make it so that the padding is somehow applied *outside* of the element's parent container? If this isn't possible, how can I simply make sure that the text of both the preview text and the link are left-aligned?

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="hero-about-container">

<div id="hero-about-text-container">    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
</div>

<a id="hero-about-link" href="localhost/wordpress/about">Read more about the history of the centre <span id="icon">&#187;</span></a>

</div>
```

...and the corresponding CSS:

```
#hero-about-text-container {
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top:30px;
}

#hero-about-link {
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-property: color, background-color;

}

#hero-about-link:hover, 
#hero-about-link:focus, 
#hero-about-link:active {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}
```

This feels like it should be a common enough problem that there's a simple solution to it, but I have no idea what that is. I know that `box-sizing:border-box` is set somewhere on ancestor elements, so that was my first thought, but setting `box-sizing:content-box` on the anchor element doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I think the two (current) answers are good solutions to what you're trying to accomplish, but your basic question: _"adding padding to the anchor element causes the whole element to shift to the right by the amount of left padding"_ — that's exactly what padding is _**meant**_ to do. Adding left padding will push the element(s) to the right, so I'm not sure why you added padding or what you expected it to do in the first place.

Comment: @StephenP That's not what padding is *meant* to do, it's just a byproduct of it. Padding is *meant* to separate content from the border, giving things like background colours more room to breathe and therefore making them less ugly, which is what I was using it for. I don't know how you weren't able to infer that purpose from the included code *and* two screenshots.

Comment: — yes, I glossed over that level of detail. `margin` will put space between blocks and `padding` will put space between the border and the content of the box. Nevertheless, `padding-left` _will_ push content to the right. You are saying "put 5px of space between the left border and the content" and then are surprised that there is space on the left, but you _said_ to put space there. The included screenshots show what is happening, they don't show the _intent_, which you don't describe, and so I couldn't infer anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to Oliver's answer, you can also achieve it with padding in place of left and right borders as well.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a.highlighted {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Some text here</p>
  <a href="#">Anchor text here</a><br>
  <a href="#" class="highlighted">Anchor text here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely a hackier solution than I was expecting, but I'll take it since it's the only one that works, thanks to margins being transparent by default. Thank you, and thanks to everyone else who posted a solution

Answer (score 1):

You could apply borders to the left and right of the element, and assign a negative margin. There might be more elegant solutions but I think this produces the effect you want?

I've provided a permanently highlighted, and highlighted on hover example. The `CSS` is the same for both.

---

## Demo

```css
.wrapper {
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
}

a:hover, a.highlighted {
  background: blue;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
  border-right: 5px solid blue;
  margin-left: -5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Some text here</p>
  <a>Anchor text here</a><br>
  <a class="highlighted">Anchor text here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `outline`:

```css
.box {
  padding:20px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
}
.box > a {
  margin:10px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#fff;
  color:#000;
  outline:10px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some long text here<br>
  <a href="">a link</a>
</div>
```

Or `box-shadow`:

```css
.box {
  padding:20px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
}
.box > a {
  padding:10px 10px 10px 0; 
  display:inline-block;
  background:#fff;
  color:#000;
  box-shadow:-10px 0 0  #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some long text here<br>
  <a href="">a link</a>
</div>
```